# Action item width in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is it possible to set the width of a single action item in the native action bar?
I have an image that is 100 pixels wide, buts the action bar shrinks it when I add it. I want it to be at full width, kind of like a wrap_content

Comment: So I found the answer in another question, found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252111/text-view-in-action-bar

Comment: ... which is no longer available... what was the solution...?

Comment: Basic idea was to inflate a custom view for the action bar. It's not ideal, but it got the job done. I would show the code I used, but I no longer have access to it. :(

Comment: Did that - but now I don't have the "click" effect. The item gets not focused for a second after a press (onclick is fired tough).

Comment: Are you talking about the UI effect where the background darkens? You'll have to set a style to get that working.